I am not able to upload the image to the backend in flutter
Is there anything wrong with this?
This is my repository.dart file:
      Future<String> uploadProfilePhoto(File photo, String uid) async {
        try {
          var request = http.MultipartRequest(
            'POST',
            Uri.parse(
                'https://7234-122-169-82-170.ngrok-free.app/api/auth/profilePicture/upload?uid=$uid'),
          );
          var photoFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('photo', photo.path);
          request.files.add(photoFile);
          var response = await request.send();
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var responseBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();
            return responseBody;
          } else {
            throw Exception('Failed to upload photo: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          debugPrint('Error uploading photo: $e');
          throw Exception(e);
        }
      }

I am watching the repository by the controller and then invoking it from the UI, so I am unsure where I am wrong.

So what is the error?

what is it printing? what is the output?

Try this with Dio()
      try {
        FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
          'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(photo.path, filename: 'photo'),
        });

        const url = 'https://';

        final response = await _dio.post(
          url,
          data: formData,
          onSendProgress: (count, total) {
            int percentage = (count / total * 100).toInt();
            print("progress: $percentage");
          },
        );

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print("success");

          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } on DioException catch (e) {
        throw Exception('Failed to upload photo: ${e.error}');
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error uploading photo: $e');
        throw Exception(e);
      }

